# Do I need information_schema, mysql, performance_Schema, phpmyadmin databases?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

It's my first time using phpmyadmin and databases. I've opened up phpMyAdmin and I already have four databases:

- information_schema
- mysql
- performance_schema
- phpmyadmin

which are full of tables.

Reading through https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema.html never answers the question: **Do I need them ? Can I delete them ?**

Comment: mysql is the database engine. Phpmyadmin is a tool to deal with databases. You opened phpMyAdmin and saw that mysql has already four databases, not phpMyAdmin. And the answer to your question is no, they are there for a reason and should not be removed if you want mysql to keep working as expected

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I find databases very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Three of the four are used internally by MySQL and if you somehow were successful in removing them, MySQL would no longer work correctly. The `phpmyadmin` one is not required by either MySQL or phpMyAdmin, but whatever means you used to install phpMyAdmin has configured it and at best you'll confuse that system and at worst you could break logging in through phpMyAdmin (until you manually edit the configuration file) through fiddling with that database. So, as Lelio Faieta said, I would leave them all alone.

What you can do, however, is hide them in phpMyAdmin. There's a configuration directive to hide databases (see https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_hide_db). You have to edit the configuration file, `config.inc.php`, and add a line like `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '^(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|phpmyadmin)$';`

Strangely, this seems to be broken in the latest phpMyAdmin; there's a bug report about it here https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16506, so depending on which phpMyAdmin version you have it might not work at the moment, but will get fixed and you can follow the bug report for more information.